# retrieving .mov PFFile from parse to display thumbnail in cell

Tags: ios, parsing, cell

i have created a parse account and placed two dummy .mov files in the backend just to practice on and learn how to retrieve .mov data and display the thumbnail image of it in a cell i have been searching the internet and i can not find anything here's my code

thumbnail:

```
-(UIImage *)loadImage:(NSString *)image
{
 // getting the frame of the video for the thumbnail
 NSString *videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:image ofType:nil];
 NSURL *vidURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:videoPath];
AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc ] initWithURL:vidURL options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator *generate = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
NSError *err = NULL;
CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 60);
CGImageRef thumbImg = [generate copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err];

return [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:thumbImg];
}
```

and this is my cellForRowAtIndex:

```
-(PFTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object

{

static NSString *cellName = @"Cell";
PFTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellName];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[PFTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellName];
}


PFFile *thumbnail = [object objectForKey:@"VidFIle"];
NSLog(@"%@",thumbnail.url);
PFImageView *thumbnailImageV = (PFImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
thumbnailImageV.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.jpg"];
```

usualy i place the method right     /\  and put the PFFile *thumbnail as the parameter casting it as a string but it doesnt work

```
//    thumbnailImageView.file = thumbnail;
//    [thumbnailImageView loadInBackground];


return cell;
}
```

what is it that im doing wrong?,  i commented out thumbnailImageView.file = thumbnail and the loadInBackground because it creates an error, now the code runs and the app comes up with the thumbnail placeholder image but i can not find a way to display the videos thumbnail in my cells that are in my backend at parse.com im going to try NSURL after i finish this Question but im still thinking there is a better way please help

P.S. im new to this about 1 year into programming so please have some patience with my questions and how i describe things thank you